# Django: how do I sort a class by an expensive-to-calculate property and make the results persistent?

Tags: django, django-models

What is best way to sort model elements by an expensive property value, and to make sure the property values persist through many request/response iterations? I might try something like:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def sorted_by_player_scores(cls, league):
        'would be very nice to be able to use a simple query here'
        from operator import itemgetter

        try:
            return sorted(cls.player_score_list, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)            

        except Attribute Error:
            players = cls.objects.all()
            for player in players:
                player_score_list = []
                try:
                    player_score_list.append((player, player.player_score))
                except AttributeError:
                    league_player = LeaguePlayer(league, player)
                    player_score_list.append((player, league_player.player_score))

            cls.player_score_list = player_score_list
            return sorted(player_score_list, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)


class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    league_size = models.IntegerField()
    scoring_rules = ...

class LeaguePlayer():
    def __init__(self, league, player):
        self.league = league
        self.player = player

    @property  # is cached_property usable/useful here?
    def player_score(self):
        self.player.player_score = very_expensive_calculation()
        return self.player.player_score

    def many_other_properties_and_methods_against_LeaguePlayers
```

I feel my problem would be a common django problem, yet I can't find a simple solution or even some general best-practice discussion. I know I could make `class LeaguePlayer()` a django model rather than simply a python class. But I don't want to have to actually create / save these datatables when the values I would be saving are very easily wrapped by the `@property` tag.

Comment: can you not compute the value on `save` and save it as a database column ?

Comment: I would have to create a distinct model for LeaguePlayers, which I have thought about doing, but that would greatly increase size and usage of the database for values, which for my purposes, are best stored in memory. If I were to do that, pickling may be a better approach, but for the ability to use django query methods against the unnecessary datatable.

Comment: but memory is not a persistent storage. How about using Haystack or some util to store the processed data?

Comment: Do it on a database level instead of in code. Much smarter and faster.

Comment: @karthikr If it was about one expensive calculation, I would use the approach you suggest. It's about several expensive calculations, some of which generate dictionaries of values with keys which depend on the type of player. So I might fall back to using a python class rather than a django model and pickle the calculated values.

Comment: @limelights Calculations require data from two separate models and some rather complex math, so I'm unsure how to push that out to the database level.